# Choosing Cartographic Font

Tags: cartography, typography

I am currently trying to choose suitable fonts for a map. A very time consuming experience - actually too time consuming as i´m not a trained typographer and will inevitably make all the classic mistakes!

In order to save myself time, and probably many other GIS users who very probably make all the classic errors when choosing font types, does anyone have any SIMPLE guidelines regarding which type of fonts should be used for standard thematic maps?

I am not talking about artistic fonts for special types of graphic, just simple clear easy to read fonts which work well together in different sizes and weights in the same map.

My main problem at the moment is trying to choose a large bold clear font for the main point theme layer annotations, and a less-weighted font for the place names. I want to have a sans-serif for the point layer which displays the names of the points in a dominant concisive factual way, but want a fitting and complementary serif-font for the place names which is thinner and less dominant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need [TypeBrewer](http://www.typebrewer.org/) - from the site:

> TypeBrewer: A Map Design Help Tool for Selecting Typography
>
> TypeBrewer is a free help tool that gives non-specialist mapmakers a
>   chance to explore typography in a semi-structured environment. It is
>   not mapmaking software. Instead of providing the functionality of a
>   graphic design program or GIS, TypeBrewer offers a quick and easy way
>   to explore typographic alternatives and see the impact that various
>   elements of type have on the overall look and feel of a map.
>   TypeBrewer is designed for mapmakers who want to learn more about map
>   typography and get practical design specifications for starting a map
>   project.

Only downside is that you need flash to make it work :-(

Comment: Typebrewer seems to be temporarily offline as they are updating it to utilize HTML instead of Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Gretchen Peterson has written a great book called "[Cartographer's Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615467946)" (on Amazon), which has about 30 pages of examples of vetted typography, all shown in a map context.

In addition to typography, the book also covers colors and patterns.  It's definitely worth purchasing for ideas.

*Not affiliated, just a fan of the book*