# Is there any alternative for TypeBrewer, since the website is down due to converstion from Flash to HTML 5?

Tags: cartography, font

I was reading the post [Choice of Cartographic Font](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80002/choice-of-cartographic-font) and the answer is suggesting the [Typebrewer](http://typebrewer.org/) website. This website is also mentioned in the 26 point (i.e., Carefully Select Typeface) mentioned in [33 Map Elements to Include in Cartographic Design: A ‘How to’ Guide to Map Making](http://gisgeography.com/map-elements-how-to-guide-map-making/) .

But, now the Typebrewer website is having down time due to their conversion from Flash to HTML5.

Does anyone know about any other alternative websites for Typebrewer?

Answer (score 2):

You can access old versions of TypeBrewer (or most other web sites for that matter) via archive.org:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160112171434/http://typebrewer.org/typebrewer.html

That works for me in Chrome (but not Firefox, which on my system has an older Flash version).